# Trying to insert multiple form data into multiple tables to the database, no error given but not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, insert

When I run my code, I get no errors and nothings being sent to the database as well and I can't seem to figure out what the problem could be here ?

I am new to this forum and mysql and php as well and Im not really sure if this is the right way of inserting the datas when you have multiple tables to fill in

or it could be something to do with the incorrect html input attributes?

```
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpass);

        $db_select = mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db);
          if (!$db_select) {
           die ("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
          }

          $query = "SELECT * FROM members, login, skills, indivoffers";
          $result = mysql_query($query);

         if (isset($_POST['mrmrs'],$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['gender'],$_POST['addr1'],
                   $_POST['addr2'],$_POST['city'],$_POST['postcode'],$_POST['hometel'],$_POST['mobtel'],
                   $_POST['email'],$_POST['job'],$_POST['user'],$_POST['pass'],$_POST['skill1'],
                   $_POST['skill2'],$_POST['skill3'],$_POST['skill4'],$_POST['skill5'],$_POST['skill6'],
                   $_POST['skill7'],$_POST['skill8'],$_POST['skill9'],$_POST['ortitle'],$_POST['message'],
                   $_POST['offereq'],$_POST['cost'],$_POST['pay'])){
          $title = $_POST['mrmrs'];
          $name = $_POST['fname'];
          $name2 = $_POST['lname'];
          $gender = $_POST['gender'];
          $address1 = $_POST['addr1'];
          $address2 = $_POST['addr2'];
          $city = $_POST['city'];
          $pc = $_POST['postcode'];
          $telhome = $_POST['hometel'];
          $telmob = $_POST['mobtel'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $job = $_POST['job'];

         $username = $_POST['user'];
         $password = $_POST['pass'];

        $skill1 = $_POST['skill1'];
        $skill2 = $_POST['skill2'];
        $skill3 = $_POST['skill3'];
        $skill4 = $_POST['skill4'];
        $skill5 = $_POST['skill5'];
        $skill6 = $_POST['skill6'];
        $skill7 = $_POST['skill7'];
        $skill8 = $_POST['skill8'];
        $skill9 = $_POST['skill9'];

         $titleor = $_POST['ortitle'];
         $mess = $_POST['message'];
         $offerequest  = $_POST['offereq'];
         $cost = $_POST['cost'];
         $pay = $_POST['pay'];

         $sql = "INSERT INTO members (Mr/Mrs, fname, lname, gender, DOB, addr1, addr2, city, postcode, telnohome, telnomob, email, job)
            VALUES ('$title','$name','$name2', '$gender', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$pc', '$telhome', '$telmob', '$email', '$job')";
        $letsid = mysql_insert_id( $db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO login (letsID,username, password)
          VALUES (letsID),'$username','$password')";
        $letsid = mysql_insert_id( $db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO skills (letsID, skill1, skill2, skill3, skill4, skill5, skill6, skill7, skill8, skill9)
          VALUES (letsID,'$skill1', '$skill2', '$skill3', '$skill4', '$skill5', '$skill6', '$skill7', '$skill8','$skill9')";
        $letsid = mysql_insert_id( $db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO indivoffers (letsID, title, message, offer/request, cost, pay)
          VALUES (letsID,'$titleor','$mess', '$offerequest', '$cost', '$pay')";
        $letsid = mysql_insert_id( $db);
         }

     ?>
```

Comment: you don't actully **run** the queries

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the querys correctly but you aren't actually executing them.

So instead of doing `<?php $sql = "INSERT INTO ..."; ?>` you can do something like this

```
<?php $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ..."); ?>
```

Setting the variable to a mysql query will execute the query so therefore this should run your querys now.

Comment: i suggest: `mysql_query($sql);` makes debugging easier.